# "A big deal" vs "(a) big of a deal"

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang, idiomatic-language

What are the differences between the following:

> 1. Maybe you don't see moving in together as **a big deal** as I do?
> 2. Maybe you don't see moving in together as **big of a deal** as I do?
> 3. Maybe you don't see moving in together as **a big of a deal** as I do?

Comment: You missed option 4… "Maybe you don't see moving in together as as big a deal as I do." [note 'as as'] which looks clunky, but is the closest to correct without re-casting the entire sentence. You can't have 'big of', you could have 'much of'.

Comment: *Big of* is fine in American English, as long as we're talking about informal speech.

Comment: FWIW In BrE I would say "as big a deal as".

Answer (score 2):

number 1 is grammatical, though it could use a comma after "deal".  I take it to mean that the speaker considers it to be a *big deal*, but he suspects that the hearer does **not** consider it to be a *big deal*

Number 2, as others pointed out, needs another "as".  Thus fixed, it would mean that perhaps both the speaker and the hearer consider it a *big deal*, or perhaps not, but in any case the speaker thinks he considers it a *bigger* deal than the hearer does.

Number 3 is ungrammatical. One does not say "as a big of ...". It does not make sense to use the article "a" with "big", because "big" is a modifier, not a substantive.

Comment: Yes. 'big of' as here is a (mainly American) error.

Answer (score 1):

As Tetsujin says: you need *as* twice:

**Maybe you don't see moving in together *as as* big (of) a deal as I do?

--No, I don't see moving in together as that big (of) a deal.**

You see or regard something *as* {X}.

X = as big (of) a deal as I do.

Alternative: You think something is {X}.   [without "as"]

**Maybe you don't think moving in together is as big (of) a deal as I do.**