# It was not that big of a deal

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It was not that big of a deal.

What's the meaning of 'of' in 'of a deal'?

The phrase 'of a deal' is an adjective or an adverb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A big deal" vs "(a) big of a deal"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56449/a-big-deal-vs-a-big-of-a-deal)

Comment: @StuartF: Seeing your linked Q was more recent than mine, I was initially minded to vote to close that as well as this one in favour of the "sofa" Q. But looking more closely, it's not obvious to me your later one is particularly concerned with whether or not to include "of" in constructions of the general form ***not that close** [of] **a match***, so I'll leave it. *This* one exactly matches the "sofa" one, though.

Comment: To me, it doesn't have any meaning and I wouldn't use it, but others find it acceptable.

Comment: I sometimes include "of" in such contexts, sometimes not. Always in *This isn't **much of an** answer*, rarely / never in *She's **too young** [of] **a** girl to get married*.

Comment: "Of a deal" is a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "big". The NP "that big of a deal" is occasionally found as an alternant to the much more common "that big a deal", where "that big" is an adjective phrase modifying the head NP " a deal".

Comment: To BillJ, Kate, Fumble, Stuart. Can I regard the 'of' here as a 'subject case marker'? Like 'for' in "It is easy for me to pass the test."?